# Large company: Made up of organizations or departments?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

Say you have a large 20,000+ company with many different sections, or areas. Say for example Apple would have a section for iOS development, one for Mac, one for HR, one for support, etc.

What is the better word to call these different sections: organizations or departments? I'm thinking "Organization" should only refer to the topmost level, the entire company.

Comment: This question really doesn't have an answer. Each company has its own names for these sections, and the names vary. Different companies  might call the top-level sections *divisions,* *centers,* *departments,* *organizations,* *units,* or who-knows-what. In at least some companies, a *department* is a much smaller piece, and the top-level ones have a different name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of Apple, I would agree that *departments* is the better word. HR is a department, as is Support.

Generally speaking, an entity *can* comprise several organizations, but in that case I would call that entity itself an *organization* (or, in case the entity is commercial, *corporation*). As a simple example, the [UN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations) is an organization, but so are its agencies such as the [UNTSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Truce_Supervision_Organization) and the [WHO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Health_Organization).

Looking at the Merriam-Webster definitions, I see that *organization* is an "association, society", while *department* is "a major division of a business". HR, Support, and iOS Development are certainly major divisions of Apple, but they can't be labeled as societies or associations in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than using organization or department, IMHO the right term is *functional groups*.

Comment: That isn't quite an accepted/used term, is it?

Answer (score 0):

A company usually has departments; a large company may have divisions (which in turn have departments within them).

I think "department" and "division" have a stronger connotation of hierarchy than "organization" does.  Organizations can be looser associations, while the engineering department has a definite reporting chain (to the CTO or whomever).